# In original Planet of the Apes, is the statue's head really the only remnant of the city?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes

In original *Planet of the Apes* film, could it really be possible that the only remnant of the city would be the statue's head?  Aren't there a lot of structures that would be more likely to survive all that time?

Comment: Yes, but those structures were intentionally destroyed.  "You maniacs, you blew it up!"

Comment: I think most of those structures are buried underground. In the sequel, they go underground into other New York City structures. Not sure why the other, taller structures are not also protruding, but it could just be Heston's angle of approach (SoL is geographically separated from the rest of the city).

Comment: That wasn't a statue.  It was the hand of the *Mega Maid* robot-ship.

Comment: @Paul: *were* there any taller structures when the movie was made?  (Just speculation, I have no idea.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - at the time the movie was filmed, there were at least six buildings in New York taller than the statue. In fact, the Chrysler Building and the Empire State Building were more than 3 times as tall. When the movie took place - in the year 3978 - who can say what was left standing and what wasn't?

Comment: @Omegacron: good point.  In fact, a better question would be how come the statue's head was still there.  I doubt it would really last that long. :-)

Comment: @Omegacron Given where the statue was located, major geological changes had clearly occurred. There was an _ocean_ where Manhattan used to be....

Comment: @HarryJohnston - remember, the statue isn't concrete, though. The outer skin is copper, several inches thick, welded & bolted onto a steel frame. So it's entirely possible that it would still be around long after concrete structures had eroded or fallen apart. Considering that there are cliff-like rocks right behind it, though, the bigger question is how it's still standing upright and/or not buried.

Answer (score 20):

A big assumption is that the statue remained on her pedestal on the island, and even that the statue is intact. It's entirely possible that she was ripped from her moorings and deposited elsewhere nearby, either in whole, or in part.

But, let's work with that assumption for the moment. I think some confusion comes from the fact that many of the images we see of Lady Liberty show her with the famous NYC skyline directly behind her. However, that skyline is actually off to her left (observers right). Directly behind her is New Jersey!

Heston is facing in roughly the direction given by the red arrow below:

[image]

As you can see, not a lot to see there.

Comment: I like this answer. However, it doesn't directly answer the question, but rather just posits why you didn't **see** any ruins of Manhattan (existing or not) in the shot. After all the whole point of that scene was that it was his first inkling of where he really was. If there were derilect skyscrapers around too (that the camera just didn't bother to pan to), it makes no sense.

Comment: @T.E.D. I wouldn't have high hopes of these things still standing a few decades after the humanity stopped caring for them.

Comment: There's a big plastic dinosaur from Liberty Science Center somewhere in the direction of that arrow.

Comment: interesting idea - though, the statue is certainly intact at least down to the shoulder since the head and arm are both in the same relative position. If the head had been torn off, it's unlikely it would be deposited in the same position next to the arm

Comment: Not quite sure why and I have not seen this film for at least ten years ( and never was interested in the newer rebooted ones ) but I always assumed it was the complete statue , at least the "body" part of it anyway discounting any build or mountings

Answer (score 4):

In the second movie of this series, it is shown that the mutants living in the old city have the mental capability to  project illusions - recall, Taylor disappears by falling through *what appears to be* a solid stone wall.  The towers of NYC are hidden behind these illusions - as is shown later, when the ape army gets past the illusions and sees the heavily eroded skyscrapers.

Answer (score 3):

[Beneath the Planet of the Apes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beneath_the_Planet_of_the_Apes) - New York (in the year 3979):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do see the ruins of New York. In Beneath the Planet of the Apes, there is a model shot of the nuked ruins.

Comment: Can you provide a clip or a video to show what you're referring to?

Answer (score -3):

Short answer: Yes, based on what is presented on-screen: It really is the only remnant. It is also the only remnant Taylor sees.
I re-iterate: On-screen!
We (the audience) have absolutely no way of knowing whether, in fact, there are also other remnants ***visible off-screen***. For all we know, the Eiffel Tower might still be standing in Paris, and the Golden Gate Bridge might still be standing in San Francisco.
That is the definitive answer about the appearance of remnants on-screen.
If you have a question about what remnants might still be in existence elsewhere in the world off-screen - please submit a separate question.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to substantiate this, or is it just your personal opinion?

Comment: "short answer": if you have a longer answer, with some evidence (analysis, quotes, you name it), we'd be glad to read it. Don't hesitate to [edit] your answer.